# how to find the upper alpha characters with space between them using python

Tags: python, list, file, text-extraction, data-extraction

I have a text file from which i want to extract the headings which are upper case and with spaces in them. So, first i store the data in the list **l1** and then i tried the following code:

```
l1=[]
headings=[""]
with open(TextFile,'rt',encoding="utf8") as IpFile:
    for j in IpFile:
        l1.append(str(j).strip())

for line in l1:
    if(line.isupper() and line.isalpha() or line.isspace()):
        headings.append(line)
```

but it returns only single word heading as **isalpha** does not alow space characters. So how can i extract the heading with more than one word having space between them. I tried to find out but there is no method in python which returns only alpha characters with spaces. so, how to extract them ?

And also can anyone tells me instead of appending the headings into new list, can i split them from the original list. like if i have a text line in the list and it contains heading then it splits the text and heading into two different lines within that list. Is that possible to do so?

**Updated Question:**
If my upper case words also contains some symbol **e.g. ABC/DEF** how can i extract that word?

I can't find any method to do this. So, i tried it using reg ex.:

```
case=re.findall(r"\A[A-Z-\/.]+[A-Z]+|\A[A-Z]+\s[A-Z]+\Z|\A[A-Z]{5,}", reg)
```

but it also returns the too small length characters. How to avoid that?

Comment: if i do so, it started extracting the upper values with digits _e.g.- ABC123_ and i only want upper alpha space characters values.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `replace` method before:

```
line = "T E S T"

line = line.replace(" ", "")

print(line)

# prints
# TEST
```

If you want something more sophisticated (more control, catch more complex string structures) I would suggest looking for the [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) module.

Comment: These are Heading i can't remove the space between them. Some headings are long it will create a mess

Comment: Yes, but you can remove spaces for your check and `append` the actual line

Answer (score 0):

```
l1=[]
headings=[""]
temp = ""
with open(TextFile,'rt',encoding="utf8") as IpFile:
    for j in IpFile:
        l1.append(str(j).strip())

for line in l1:
    temp = line.replace(" ","")
    if(temp.isupper() and temp.isalpha() or temp.isspace()):
        headings.append(line)
```

Comment: Thanks for help. can you also tells me instead of appending the headings into new list, can i split them from the original list. like if i have a text line in the list and it contains heading then it splits the text and heading into two different lines within that list